# Precise estimation of air properties as a function of temperature at 1 atm

Tags: gas-laws, conductivity, viscosity

Are there any tables with empirical equations to calculate properties of air as a function of a temperature at 1 atm?

For example, NIST provides such equations for a large number of gases, but I was not able to find such solution for air, where I would specifically like to obtain:

- Dynamic viscosity,
- Specific heat,
- Prandtl number,
- Thermal conductivity,
- Thermal diffusivity.

It would be best, if I could put these calculation in *MS Excel*, because I need to change these values with respect to temperature in multiple equations.

Comment: Properties of air are not precise.

Comment: As @Mithoron states, "air" varies, particularly as to water vapor. This was a problem for carburetors, the design of which often ignored that, leading to icing of the venturi.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links that look like they might be useful, there seems to be promising information on some engineering resource sites:

- https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470516430.app2
  This is the appendix from what appears to be an engineering textbook, it gives a chart of the information you're looking for at 1 atm and 15 C. It also walks you through the temperature dependent equations for some of the properties.
- https://www.me.psu.edu/cimbala/me433/Links/Table_A_9_CC_Properties_of_Air.pdf
  This is a table of the properties of air at 1 atm from -150C to 2000C. It doesn't provide equations but you could maybe enter the data into excel and run a regression to extract a an equation.
- https://irc.wisc.edu/properties/ This is a handy little calculator that outputs a whole host of properties of fluids, including dry air.

The point that has been made about water vapor fluctuations is valid, but most calculations of air properties assume dry air with constant composition.

Comment: I have a similar table for air properties at 1 atm. I also found some other calculators, but calculating every values in a calculator is not very productive for my purposes, however, the "Appendix B" looks very promising - I will have to try the differences for values computed as a temperature function to those in the chart, if the correlation is satisfying, I'm all settled :).

Answer (score 0):

A lot can be found at [engineeringtoolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com) , like [air-prandtl-number-viscosity-heat-capacity-thermal-conductivity](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-prandtl-number-viscosity-heat-capacity-thermal-conductivity-d_2009.html).

The data are ( at least mostly ) presented as combination of an online calculator, tabelated numerical values and charts, instead of specific empirical formulas. But it should not be a big deal to invent some interpolation or approximation formulas for those tabelated numerical values.

See also the Related documents section in the latter link, a chosen topics:

> Air - Composition and Molecular Weight
> Air - Density at varying pressure and constant temperatures
> Air - Density, Specific Weight and Thermal Expansion Coefficient at Varying Temperature and Constant Pressures
> Air - Diffusion Coefficients of Gases in Excess of Air
> Air - Dynamic and Kinematic Viscosity
> Air - Molecular Weight and Composition - Dry air
> Air - Properties at Gas-Liquid Equilibrium Conditions
> Air - Specific Heat at Constant Temperature and Varying Pressure
> Air - Thermal Conductivity
> Air - Thermal Diffusivity
> Air - Thermophysical Properties

Comment: Thanks, as matter of fact, the engineeringtoolbox was the first thing I found, however, when I had to always fill out their calculator (which is great for its purpose), I realized that I need to put calculations to MS Excel, because it was very slow.

Comment: But putting a table to Excel and processing some numerical analysis.... E.g. the obvious and trivial least square method for a polynomial or rational function via Excel Solver..... At least you know this is the last resort option if you do not find anything better.

Comment: I know... it won't be horrible. In general, I was just very curious whether I missed any empirical equations, which would solve my problem most efficiently.